# Color listing in xterm terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, debian, xterm

I installed a minimal debian and i'm trying to set everything by myself, so i'm trying to tune my default terminal Xterm by giving it some colors, after some research i found that this can be done either by editing the .Xresources file so i can give the first 16 colors in Hexa code (#numbers) or by editing the .bashrc file.
After some research seems like the second solution is more dynamic 'cause i can specify the colors of files by extensions, the problem is that all the articles on the net use a color code very weird :

```
.gz  01;31
.bz2 01;31
.deb 07;31
.rpm 01;31
.jar 01;31
```

I want to know if there's a way to use RGB code color or hexa color so i can have more flexibility with my directory and files listings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no RGB support, terminal emulators are limited to display a limited set of colors (a palette with 64 combinations of foreground and background, if I'm not mistaken). If ease of use is what concerns you, you can always declare several variables for the predefined colors, something like:

```bash
readonly BLACK_FONT_BLACK_BACKGROUND='30;40'     
readonly BLACK_FONT_RED_BACKGROUND='30;41'       
readonly BLACK_FONT_GREEN_BACKGROUND='30;42'     
readonly BLACK_FONT_YELLOW_BACKGROUND='30;43'
...
readonly WHITE_FONT_CYAN_BACKGROUND='37;46'
readonly WHITE_FONT_WHITE_BACKGROUND='37;47'
```

And use them later like:

```bash
.gz  $BLACK_FONT_YELLOW_BACKGROUND
```

The following is a table with the color codes for foreground and background:

```
  Color   Foreground   Background
  -------------------------------
  black       30           40
  red         31           41
  green       32           42
  yellow      33           43
  blue        34           44
  magenta     35           45
  cyan        36           46
  white       37           47
  -------------------------------
```

If generating all the color names variables manually is too tedious, you can use the following python script:

```python
 colors = ['black', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white']; 
 index = 0
 for x in ["{0}_FONT_{1}_BACKGROUND='{2};{3}'".format(colors[i].upper(), colors[j].upper(), i + 30, j + 40) for i in xrange(0, 8) for j in xrange(0, 8)]: 
     print x.ljust(38) + "#" + str(index) 
     index += 1
```

Comment: Thank you sir! can i combine the usage of .Xresource file and .bashrc for some special extension?

Comment: Do you mean creating a new special file and including both `.Xresource` and `.bashrc` files? Yes, you can include them in any script by typing `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I meant can i give my .Xressources file the 16 first colors in hexa code and for some special files like source files (c++ header and cpp files) different colors using .bashrc file?

Comment: Yes, is possible, beware the order of loading for the files though, and also take into account that `.Xresources` usage is [deprecated](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources)

Comment: Thank you. I use xrdb to load the file as suggested in the arch wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you can't use the RBG color code (or HSV, or HCL). You may find the documentation with:

```
$ man 5 dir_colors
```

Comment: So how can i use special colors? is there some sort of table or conversion that i can use?

Comment: @Habchi, Higaro and Thomas Dickley expanded my answer and possibly answered to this comment. If any of them solved your problem, you should certify the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [@Leonardo Fontenelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4825192/leonardo-fontenelle), the place to *start* reading about GNU `ls` coloring is the [`dir_colors`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html) manual page.  The numbers used, such as `01;31` are the constants associated with what the manual page refers to as "ISO 6429 (ANSI) color sequences".  Actually the manual page is a little more obscure than it ought to be:

- the constants are *parameters* used in the ISO 6429 **SGR** (*set graphic rendition*) control sequence.  The actual standard is very detailed (see [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)).
- 01 happens to be the standard code for *bold* (the manual refers to it using the Linux-centric "brighter colors*).
- as noted by [@higuaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041822/higuaro), codes 30-37 and 40-47 form a *color palette*; all of the colors shown on the terminal at any moment come from the current palette.
- there is more than one way to update the color palette used by `xterm`; none of those are directly related to the `ls` configuration because the numbers used for referring to the palette do not contain the color information by themselves.
- you can display the *colors* and *video attributes* using the ncurses [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) utility, e.g., `tput setaf 7`.
- some (relatively) recent `ls` configurations use additional color codes outside the 30-37 / 40-47 palette, e.g., for the `aixterm` 16-color feature, or the `xterm` 88-colors or 256-colors.  The `dir_colors` manual page does not mention this.